How to execute typer program without specifying filename
Assume having tool.py file with the following content:
import typer

app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def create():
    ...


@app.command()
def delete():
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()

It can be executed using typer tool.py run create.
I'm wondering if there is a way to execute it without specifying .py extension? Something like typer tool run create. Or using "an alias" instead of filename e.g. tool.py > talias and use typer talias run create.

I’m genuinely curious as to why it matters so much if you pass a file name with its extension as part of your invocation.

@esqew It doesn't matters so much, I'm wondering if it's even possible. Because this is how cli interface looks like. In my opinion, specifying a file path is more confusing than a sequence of commands and arguments. Also, the details that the interface is implemented in Python seem unnecessary to me

@AndrewYim In this case it will not be a Python module and it will be impossible to import it, which is what typer does

did you tried to rename it ? Maybe it doesn't import it but loads like normal file? On Windows you many need extension only when you want to click on file to run it with default program (python or typer) but when you run it like python script then it may no need extension (at least on Linux it doesn't need it)

BTW: on Linux you can even add shebang in first like #!/path/to/python or #!/path/to/typer and change its mode to executable - chmod +x tool.py - and then you can rename it to tool and run without extension and also without typer  - only tool run create - because Linux use information from shebang to run script.

@furas Yep, I tried to rename it, but as far as I understood, typer implements a "wrapper" over a file and imports it like a module, that's why it's impossible. I will try to dive deeper in the shebang direction, thanks!

it is strange because documentation shows that you can run directly with python tool.py . But maybe this method doesn't have some functionality

partial solution: put typer tool.py %* in batch/bash script file and then you can use any name and run it without typing typer
